# Hydrostatic pressure in a vase at different depths

Tags: pressure, water

I am building a water level sensing device on the base of Arduino. The sensor is the [eTape by Milontech](http://milonetech.com/products/standard-etape-assembly). The resistance changes almost linearly with depth as the sensor is immersed in liquid ([datasheet](http://www.original.milonetech.com/uploads/Standard_eTape_Datasheet.pdf)). The resistance gradient is 150 $\Omega$/inch.

The working principle of the sensor is the hydrostatic pressure. The resistance is inversely proportional to the level of liquid according to the datasheet.

Suppose that for my tests I pick two water recipients. One is near cylindric, another is irregular.

[image] [image]

My question is about hydrostatic pressure for the irregular recipient. Will the pressure still be linear with the level of liquid? For the irregular shape, there is more water and thus higher (?) pressure gradient when immersing the sensor near the bottom. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

If you take any HORIZONTAL slice of your container the pressure is the same all across it and is equal to:

P$=\rho g h$

where $\rho$ is the density of the material that you have, $g$ gravity acceleration and $h$ is the height of column above that slice. So the "more water" in the irregular glass accumulate at higher column and makes bigger pressure.

If the shape of your glass was a glass with a curl OUT of the normal shape (yours has a curl IN) then still the pressure on the liquid around that curl is the same as the pressure of liquid in **the points at the same height**.

Then no matter where your sensor is or what the shape of your container is, the pressure that it senses is the same across the liquid at the same height.

Hope this helps